# Ext.net Row Editing Old and New Values

Tags: extjs, ext.net, gridpanel, listeners

Based on this [thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?17341-GridPanel-AfterEdit-Direct-Event-and-Original-Value), i'm trying to get old and new values from edited row/cell. But always **rowIndex** is empty. How can i get this values? There is another way to catch this informations in server side?

Here is my grid. Thanks!

```
<ext:GridPanel runat="server"
                                        Frame="true"
                                        Layout="FitLayout"
                                        MarginSpec="5 0 5 0"
                                        ID="Janelas01">
                                        <Store>
                                            ...
                                            </ext:Store>
                                        </Store>
                                        <ColumnModel runat="server">
                                            <Columns>
                                                ...
                                                <ext:Column runat="server"
                                                    DataIndex="Meta"
                                                    Text="Meta / H"
                                                    Flex="1"
                                                    Align="Center">
                                                    <Editor>
                                                        <ext:NumberField
                                                            runat="server"
                                                            AllowBlank="false"
                                                            AllowDecimals="true"
                                                            Step="0.01">
                                                        </ext:NumberField>
                                                    </Editor>
                                                </ext:Column>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </ColumnModel>
                                        <SelectionModel>
                                            <ext:RowSelectionModel runat="server" />
                                        </SelectionModel>
                                        <Plugins>
                                            <ext:RowEditing runat="server">
                                                <Listeners>
                                                    <BeforeEdit Handler="this.oldValues = Ext.net.clone(this.grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).data);" />
                                                </Listeners>
                                                <DirectEvents>
                                                    <Edit OnEvent="GridPanel_AfterEdit">
                                                        <ExtraParams>
                                                            <ext:Parameter Name="old" Value="this.oldValues" Mode="Raw" Encode="true" />
                                                            <ext:Parameter Name="new" Value="this.grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).data" Mode="Raw" Encode="true" />
                                                        </ExtraParams>
                                                    </Edit>
                                                </DirectEvents>
                                            </ext:RowEditing>
                                        </Plugins>
                                    </ext:GridPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. Credits to [@fabricio.murta](http://forums.ext.net/member.php?15031-fabricio-murta)!

I just change this piece of code:

```
<Plugins>
            <ext:RowEditing runat="server">
                <Listeners>
                    <BeforeEdit Handler="this.oldValues = Ext.net.clone(e.record.data);" />
                </Listeners>
                <DirectEvents>
                    <Edit OnEvent="OnAfterEdit">
                        <ExtraParams>
                            <ext:Parameter Name="old" Value="this.oldValues" Mode="Raw" Encode="true" />
                            <ext:Parameter Name="new" Value="e.record.data" Mode="Raw" Encode="true" />
                        </ExtraParams>
                    </Edit>
                </DirectEvents>
            </ext:RowEditing>
        </Plugins>
```